# Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

When trying run below code I get **Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent** when **return GetData();** is invoked it starts execution of the function but immediately returns the control back with the error. Observed during debugging.

Basically the code tries to fetch key from MySQL DB if doesn't exist in redis DB

All database and redis related modules are written in separate file so as to reuse it.

**somefile.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var dbModules = require('../common/database');
var redisModules = require("../common/redismodule");

function getSettings(request, response) 
{
    return GetData();

    function GetData() 
    {
        return redisModules.GetRedisValue("key")
        .then(function (result) 
        {
            if (!result) 
                return SetData();      
            else 
                return result;
        })
        .then(function (result) 
        {
            response.status(200).send({ value : result });
        })
        .catch(function (e) 
        {
            response.status(500).send();
        };
    }

    function SetData()
    {
        return dbModules.executeQuery('query')
        .then(function(results) 
        {
            // some code
            return 'some_key';
        })
        .then(function (result) 
        {
            redisModules.setRedisValue('key', result);
        });
    }
}
```

**database.js**

File for handling database connections

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');

pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: '',
  connectionLimit: 4
});


module.exports = {

  getSqlConnection: function()
  {
      return pool.getConnection().disposer(function(connection) 
      {
          console.log("came here in releasing connection function");
          pool.releaseConnection(connection);
      });
  },

  executeQuery: function(sqlQuery)
  {
      return Promise.using(module.exports.getSqlConnection(), function(connection) 
      {
          return connection.query(sqlQuery)
          .then(function(results) 
          {
              return results;
          });
      });
  }
};
```

**redismodule.js**

File for handling redis get, set concepts

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var constants = require('../common/contants');

var redisClient;        // Global (Avoids Duplicate Connections)

module.exports = 
{
    OpenRedisConnection : function()
    {
        if (redisClient == null) 
        {
            redisClient = require("redis").createClient(6379, 'localhost');
        }
    },
    isRedisConnectionOpened : function()
    {
        if (redisClient && redisClient.connected == true) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(redisClient)
                redisClient.end();  // End and open once more

            module.exports.OpenRedisConnection();
            return true;
        }
    },
    GetRedisValue: function (key) 
    {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            if(!module.exports.isRedisConnectionOpened())
                 reject("Redis connection failure");

            redisClient.get(key, function (error, result) 
            {
                if (error) 
                {
                    reject(error);
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (result == null)
                        resolve();    // Key not present so create
                    else
                        resolve(result);
                }
            });
        }); 
    },
    SetRedisValue: function (key, value) 
    {           
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            if(!module.exports.isRedisConnectionOpened())
                 reject("Redis connection failure");

            redisClient.set(key, value, 'EX', 1000, 
            function(err,reply) 
            {
                if (reply == 'OK')
                    resolve(value);         // Send the value
                else
                    reject(err);
            });
        }); 
    }
};
```

The execution starts when getSettings function is called.

I have just included all the code so that if its correct it might be useful for others.

**Corrected Answer**

**somefile.js**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var dbModules = require('database');
var redisModules = Promise.promisifyAll(require("redismodule"));

async function getSettings(request, response) {

    try {
        var data = redisModules.GetRedisValue("key");
        if (!data)
            data = await SetData();

        return response.status(200).send({
            value: data
        });

    } catch (error) {
        return response.status(500).send({
            'error': 'Try after some time'
        });
    }    

    function SetData() {
        let result = dbModules.executeQuery('query')
        return redisModules.setRedisValue('key', result);
    }
}
```

**database.js**

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    connectionLimit: 4
});

function getSqlConnection() {
    return pool.getConnection().disposer(function (connection) {
        console.log("came here in releasing connection function");
        pool.releaseConnection(connection);
    });
}

module.exports = {
    executeQuery: function (sqlQuery) {
        return Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function (connection) {
            return connection.query(sqlQuery)
                .then(function (results) {
                    return results;
                });
        });
    }
};
```

**redismodule.js**

```
var redisClient; // Global (Avoids Duplicate Connections)

// Making the below functions are private
function openRedisConnection() {
    if (redisClient && redisClient.connected == true) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (redisClient)
            redisClient.end(); // End and open once more

        redisClient = require("redis").createClient(6379,
            process.env.REDIS_URL, {
                auth_pass: process.env.REDIS_PASS
            });
        redisClient.selected_db = 1;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    GetRedisValue: function (key) {
        openRedisConnection();

        redisClient.get(key, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                return error;
            } else {
                if (result)
                    return result;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        });
    },
    SetRedisValue: function (key, value) {

        openRedisConnection();

        redisClient.set(key, value, 'EX', 1000,
            function (err, reply) {
                if (reply == 'OK')
                    resolve(value); // Send the value
                else
                    reject(err);
            });
    }
};
```

Comment: Well yes, in case of an error both the `catch` error handler and the subsequent `then` callback are trying to send a response.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, i tried debugging before it even starts with redisModules.GetRedisValue("key") this line of code the control is returned. I tried using breakpoints, logging and observing

Comment: Even with that `.then(...).catch(...)` fix, the code still has issues, yes? This is what I see :
In `#somefile.js`, 
(1) `GetData()` doesn't return anything - should be a promise; 
(2) `GetData()` calls `SetData()` - should probably be `setElection_Data()`; 
(3) `setElection_Data()` doesn't return anything - should ba a promise.
In `database.js`, `pool` is not localized. 
In `redismodule.js`, 
(1) `new reject("...")` should be `reject(new Error('...'))`;
(2) `OpenRedisConnection()` and `isRedisConnectionOpened()` can probably be kept private to the module.

Comment: hi @Roamer-1888 i have updated my original post with the changes you have mentioned can you check once. Can you post with the changes you have mentioned regarding `pool is not localized` and `OpenRedisConnection, isRedisConnectionOpened` to be made as private

Comment: What has happened here is that you have amended your question in response to Bergi's comment, which should, in all probability, fix the issue. I have made some further suggestions and you have amended your code again. Whereas it's good that your are taking the advice offered, the original problem is no longer observable in the question, therefore it is of minimal help to anyone who visits later. If you have to edit a question, by all means add to it or correct errors, but don't amend it to reflect the solution.

Comment: sorry @Roamer-1888 i'll just correct it can you just reply back to the previous comment which i have made.

Comment: Re 'pool`, it just needs `var` to make it `var pool = mysql.createPool({...});`

Comment: Re `OpenRedisConnection` and `isRedisConnectionOpened`, the way members are scoped in Node.js, any local member declared in a "required" file is not global (as you might expect if you are used to writing client-side js). Instead such members are private to the module defined by that file. Only members exposed through `module.exports` are publicly accessible from outside the module. All I'm suggesting is that those two functions needn't be public, therefore write them as `function OpenRedisConnection() {...}` and `function isRedisConnectionOpened() {...}` and adjust calls to them accordingly.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sorry for the delay, i have updated with the correct answer. Just let me know if it fine.

Comment: Yes, that looks about right. One mistake pops out - `module.exports.openRedisConnection()` should now be just `openRedisConnection()`.

Comment: Also:
(1) I would move `.then(...).catch(...)` from `GetData()` and chain it to the `return GetData();` call. The nett effect is identical but `GetData()` now does just that and nothing else.
(2) `openRedisConnection()` and `isRedisConnectionOpened()` are probably better rationalised into one function, `getRedisConnestion()`, which returns `redisClient` rather than `true`.
(3) With the help of `bluebird.js` you can promisify `redisClient` methods with `Promise.promisifyAll(redisClient)` and simplify `redismodulel.GetRedisValue()` and `redismodulel.SetRedisValue()`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i have just updated the corrected answer.
One thing which is not done is since redisClient is declared globally within the file, so not returning it instead re-using it whenever its required.
let me know if everything is fine.

Comment: Looking better, but you don't want to promisify your `redismodule.js`; instead, within that module, promisify `redis` itself. 
Bluebird's [`Promise.promisifyAll()` documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) actually includes an example which says that, once promisified, redis will give client instances that have a bunch of promise-returning methods. These should include `redisClient.getAsync()` and `redisClient.setAsync()` - use these instead of `redisClient.get()` and `redisClient.set()`.

Comment: With redis promisified and `openRedisConnection()` returning `redisClient` as I suggested (despite it being accessible as an outer var), you should be afforded the syntactic convenience of writing both `.getRedisValue()` as a one-liner - `'getRedisValue': function(key) { return openRedisConnection().getAsync(key); }` (and similarly for `setRedisValue()`).

Comment: can you provide redismodule code by updating it, if you don't mind. I don't want to re-create the redisclient object and also i have to select redis database 1 since 0 is used for other purpose. So can you just provide me the code.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 i understood your concept your trying to say but just confused trying to implement the above features which i have mentioned

Comment: OK, it's time for me to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I see it :

**somefile.js**

```
var dbModules = require('../common/database');
var redisModules = require("../common/redismodule");

function getSettings(request, response) {
    function getData() {
        return redisModules.getRedisValue('key')
        .then(function (result) {
            return result || setData();
        });
    }

    function setData() {
        return dbModules.executeQuery('query')
        .then(function(results) {
            return redisModules.setRedisValue('key', results);
        });
    }

    return getData()
    .then(function(result) {
        response.status(200).send({ value: result });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        response.status(500).send();
    });
}
```

**database.js**

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    connectionLimit: 4
});

function getSqlConnection() {
    return pool.getConnection().disposer(function(connection) {
        console.log("came here in releasing connection function");
        pool.releaseConnection(connection);
    });
}

module.exports = {
    'executeQuery': function(sqlQuery) {
        return Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function(connection) {
            return connection.query(sqlQuery);
        });
    }
};
```

**redismodule.js**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require('redis'));
var redisClient = null;

function openRedisConnection() {
    if (!redisClient || !redisClient.connected) {
        if (redisClient) {
            redisClient.end(); // End and open once more
        }
        redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, process.env.REDIS_URL, {
            auth_pass: process.env.REDIS_PASS
        });
        redisClient.selected_db = 1;
    }
    return redisClient;
}

module.exports = {
    'getRedisValue': function(key) {
        return openRedisConnection().getAsync(key); // here we call the promise-returning .getAsync() method, created by Promise.promisifyAll()
    },
    'setRedisValue': function(key, value) {
        return openRedisConnection().setAsync(key, value, 'EX', 1000); // here we call the promise-returning .setAsync() method, created by Promise.promisifyAll()
    }
};
```

My main contributions are in `somefile.js` and `redismodule.js`. The third module, `database.js` has been tidied but nothing more than that.

Things like `dbModules.executeQuery('query')` and `redisModules.getRedisValue('key')` need to be addressed but I guess you know what you are doing there.